# Ajax in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, ajax, eclipse, rcp

Is there a way to use any AJAX like components in an Eclipse RCP application though without migrating to a RAP platform? If migration is the only way, is there any tool/wizard that will help the application to be converted from RCP to RAP platform?

Any pointers will be of great help.

Comment: You can check out the Nebula Project here: http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/ although I'm not sure whether they have a solution for you or not.

Comment: What do you mean with "AJAX like components"?

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall. Thanks for the response. I meant to have AJAX enabled SWT controls. For example, jQuery like Grid in SWT.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a thick client or thin client (web browser)? or you want to migrate UI components from thin client to thick client (RCP)? Please clarify.

Comment: I am expecting a thick client only and not a web based component. Please provide pointers.